# numpy.where: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

<sub>I know there are other questions with the same error name, yet none of them match the np.where statement, and also I couldn't find the answer to my problem in them</sub>

So I made a pandas `DataFrame` called `data` and created a `Series` out of it called `dates`, which is:

```
dates= pd.to_datetime(pd.to_timedelta(data.a_date, unit= 'D') + pd.datetime(1960,1,1), 
                      errors= 'coerse')
```

I need to clear some of the dates because they do not match with an indicator of them in `data`, so I tried to adjust that while keeping the indexes correct using `numpy.where`,
Yet I had gotten this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2b83ed2b2468> in <module>()
----> 1 np.where(((dates.notnull()) & (data.a_IND == 0)), np.nan, dates)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: Can you please show your data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to keep the date type, substitute `np.nan` with `np.datetime64('NaT')`:

```
np.where(((dates.notnull()) & (data.a_IND == 0)), np.datetime64('NaT'), dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`np.where(cond, x, y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) says that the second and third arguments - x and y - need to be array or array_like. Also, I believe x and y must be of the same shape.

Your x is a scalar (`np.nan`) and y is an array_like object (`dates`). Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Maybe but this is a `pandas` problem. The `np.where` issue is a byproduct of a misuse of the pandas API, so this answer doesn't help OP.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem and managed to fix it by getting the `date` property from the index, i.e. this works:

`np.where(condition, df.x, df.index.date)`

And this doesn't work:

`np.where(condition, df.x, df.index)`

when the index has `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

Hope that helps!