# python pandas update overwrite=False > Invalid Type Promotion Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

I am trying to update a pandas dataframe with another dataframe in python. I want to update NaN values in a column of one dataframe, when matching equal values of other column in another dataframe.

The structure and procedure looks exactly like in the minimal example below

- int64 type column (IDX), which is used as index for the join
- float64 type column (VAL), which is used for the actual update
- datetime64 type column (DAT), only in df1 which doesn't play any role in the update, but contains NaT entries
- df1 contains a NaN value in VAL which should be updated by the matching IDX entries in df2
- only NaN values shall be updated, no overwriting of non-NaN values in VAL in df1 (therefore `overwrite=False`)

Minimal Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tabulate

#build df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IDX':[1,2],'VAL':[1,np.nan],'DAT':['2021-07-28','']})
df1['IDX'] = df1['IDX'].apply(int)
df1['VAL'] = df1['VAL'].apply(float)
df1['DAT'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DAT'], errors='coerce')

#build df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IDX':[1,2],'VAL':[1.1,2.2]})
df2['IDX'] = df2['IDX'].apply(int)
df2['VAL'] = df2['VAL'].apply(float)

#check input
print(">>> INPUT")
print("*"*15, "df1", "*"*15)
print(df1.to_markdown(tablefmt="grid"))
print(df1.dtypes)
print("*"*15, "df2", "*"*15)
print(df2.to_markdown(tablefmt="grid"))
print(df2.dtypes)

# set indices for update
df1.set_index('IDX', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('IDX', inplace=True)

# apply update
df1.update(
    other=df2,
    join='left',
    overwrite=False
)
# reset indices
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# check result
print(">>> RESULT")
print("*"*15, "df1", "*"*15)
print(df1.to_markdown(tablefmt="grid"))
```

If I use `overwrite=True` the procedure works, but also overwrites the existing VAL value in df1

```
>>> INPUT
*************** df1 ***************
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
|    |   IDX |   VAL | DAT                 |
+====+=======+=======+=====================+
|  0 |     1 |     1 | 2021-07-28 00:00:00 |
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |     2 |   nan | NaT                 |
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
IDX             int64
VAL           float64
DAT    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
*************** df2 ***************
+----+-------+-------+
|    |   IDX |   VAL |
+====+=======+=======+
|  0 |     1 |   1.1 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     2 |   2.2 |
+----+-------+-------+
IDX      int64
VAL    float64
dtype: object
>>> RESULT
*************** df1 ***************
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
|    |   IDX |   VAL | DAT                 |
+====+=======+=======+=====================+
|  0 |     1 |   1.1 | 2021-07-28 00:00:00 | <- VAL should not be overwritten
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |     2 |   2.2 | NaT                 | <- VAL updated correctly
+----+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

If I use desired setup with `overwrite=False`, the procedure fails with below error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-55c462741178> in <module>
     27     other=df2,
     28     join='left',
---> 29     overwrite=False
     30 )
     31 # reset indices

~\.conda\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in update(self, other, join, overwrite, filter_func, errors)
   6594 
   6595         In the following example, we will use ``nlargest`` to select the three
-> 6596         rows having the largest values in column "population".
   6597 
   6598         >>> df.nlargest(3, 'population')

~\.conda\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in where(cond, a, b, use_numexpr)
    250     a : return if cond is True
    251     b : return if cond is False
--> 252     use_numexpr : bool, default True
    253         Whether to try to use numexpr.
    254     

~\.conda\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _where_standard(cond, a, b)
    160     operator.or_: "|",
    161     roperator.ror_: "|",
--> 162     operator.xor: "^",
    163     roperator.rxor: "^",
    164     divmod: None,

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Checking for other posts I found a relation with the datetime64 column, containing NaT values. Indeed if I drop this column in df1 or fill it with valid dates, the procedure also works with `overwrite=False`. But since I am using the IDX column as joining index and only use the VAL column in df2, my expectation would be, that the DAT column in df1 is not affected by the join at all?

I am on Anaconda with

```
python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
pandas 1.2.2
numpy 1.19.2
```

Comment: Seems like this happens in `np.where`, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793044/numpy-where-typeerror-invalid-type-promotion) help?

Comment: This post - like many others I found online on this error message - relate to date type columns, I am not using any dates, juste pure int64 and float64. Hence I am searchig for a different root cause and solution.

Comment: Have you considered using combine method of dataframe?

Comment: It's worth trying simple `DataFrame.fillna` if you have set your indices correctly.

Comment: @Erfan interesting idea, indeed a `df1.fillna(value=df2, axis=0, inplace=True)` produces the same result in the minimal example. For my actual values however this throws an `InvalidIndexError`, maybe a hint for the root cause?

Comment: You indices are problably not the same, try with [`pd.Index.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.equals.html). The problem with your question is that your example does not represent your problem, so it's hard to answer it.

Comment: @Sajal using DataFrame.combine would require a complex function to apply this, wouln't it? From my perspective an update seems to describe my situation the best, since I only want to "combine" very specific cells in the dataframe, not combine complete rows or columns.

Comment: @Erfan the values of the indices are definitely not the same. df1 might be a subset of df2 or vice versa. I thought the DataFrame.udpate can take care of this by comparing the indices values and only apply the update on a match.

Comment: @HeXor sorry, it should be combine_first. All the NAN values would be updated then

Comment: @Erfan I updated my minimal example with non-matching indices, the update still works.

Comment: @Sajal interesting, it indeed works with combine_first, however from my understanding combine_first is using an outer / union join, while I want to use a left join, i.e. really only update df1, dropping df2 indices which are not in df1, which a combine_first adds to the resulting df?

Comment: I updated the minimal example to show the exact problem. Indeed it comes down to an additional datetime64 column, which contains null dates / NaT. Since this column does not play an role in the actual join, I didn't expect it to have any effect. I also updated to pandas 1.2.2, but the issue remains. How can I update VAL column based on IDX, carrying a DAT column along?